# use column of "super" table in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
SELECT value,(SELECT value2 FROM test AS x WHERE x.id = SUPER.id) FROM test
```

I want to get the column of the table of the main query. Is this possible without giving it a name?
Is there a replacement for the SUPER keyword I invented?

Comment: A table in main query has a name (or alias). You can use this name (alias) in correlated query.

Comment: Indeed, this is a very good use of aliases

Comment: SELECT value,(SELECT value2 FROM test AS x WHERE x.id = test.id) FROM test -> this works. thanks for the hint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand much where the `SUPER` is coming from, but if you're referring to the main `test` table, then you can proceed as below;

```
 SELECT value, 
       (SELECT value2 
        FROM TEST as Test1 
        WHERE x.id = Test1.id) 
 FROM TEST
```